# how do you know which instance in singleton pattern

Tags: java

I have a code ManagerService  that prints the instances boss1 and boss2. Both have same hashcode.  How will i come to know which boss is it boss1 or boss2.  i cannot makeout, since the instances are same hence hashcode are same. how to know  which boss is it.

```
   public class ManagerService {

    private static ManagerService managerservice;

   private ManagerService(){
    System.out.println("manager created");
     }


   public static ManagerService getInstance() {

    if (managerservice==null){
        managerservice = new ManagerService();
      }

        return managerservice;
    }

  public void doWork(){
      System.out.println("Manager is working");
      System.out.println(managerservice.hashCode());
     }
    }
```

Test Class

```
 public class ManagerServiceTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    ManagerService boss1 =  ManagerService.getInstance();
    boss1.doWork();

    ManagerService boss2 = ManagerService.getInstance();
    boss2.doWork();


    }

}
```

Comment: ``boss1`` and ``boss2`` are local variables that reference the same object. You cannot distinguish between "the two", because it is one and the same object. Your question is basically "how do i know which local variable was used?"

Answer (score 5):

The idea of the singleton pattern is that there is a single object. You only have one `ManagerService` object, which you can see for yourself by doing

```
System.out.println(boss1 == boss2);
```

which will print `true` meaning they're the exact same single object.

As for `boss1` and `boss2`, they're just variable names. Like your mother might refer to you as "my darling" and your father as "that little b***ard", there's still only one of you.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of singleton pattern is to have only one instance of this class. So naturally they will have the same hashCode(). Note, though that in your implementation in  a multi threaded environment you can create more than one instance. So you should use lock in order to prevent this. Also you need to make the constructor private.